# How to active python virtual environment (VENV) using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I want to write a python code to activate the virtual environment and then run the django local server

and this what I did

```py
import subprocess , os

input = 'path\\to\\venv\\activate.bat'

pro = subprocess.Popen(['start',input,'/k','python manage.py runserver'], shell = True, stdin= subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, text = True)

os.system('python manage.py runserver')
```

This code activates the virtual environment (VENV) but it does not run the django local server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a much cleaner approach:

```
os.system('path\to\venv\python3 manage.py runserver')
```

This way you will run the Python executable from the venv with all its packages.